# How to select matching records from one table with a field that holds an SQL expression if the expression matches a record stored in another table

Tags: postgresql

My question is related to application generated events and user subscription to these events.

There is a table in which event data is stored:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event_data (
  id           BIGSERIAL    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  type         VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  nature       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  source       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  timestamp    TIMESTAMPTZ  NOT NULL,
  initiator_id BIGINT       NOT NULL,
  account_id   BIGINT       NULL,
  site_id      BIGINT       NULL,
  resource     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  instance     BIGINT       NULL,
  message      TEXT         NULL,
  version      BIGINT DEFAULT 1,
  CONSTRAINT event_data_person_fk FOREIGN KEY (initiator_id)
  REFERENCES person (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT event_data_account_fk FOREIGN KEY (account_id)
  REFERENCES account (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT event_data_site_fk FOREIGN KEY (site_id)
  REFERENCES site (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

and a table in which event rules (i.e. user subscriptions to events) are stored:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event_rule (
  id        BIGSERIAL    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  person_id BIGINT       NOT NULL,
  trigger   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  condition TEXT         NULL,
  action    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  version   BIGINT DEFAULT 1,
  CONSTRAINT event_rule_person_fk FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
  REFERENCES person (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

In the application, a person registers interest in a particular event by specifying the `event_rule.trigger` which matches values in `event_data.type`. The `event_rule.condition` is to become the `WHERE` clause to determine if the `event_data` record matches the condition (no condition is an option in which case the rule would match based on `event_data.type = event_rule.trigger`). If the rule matches, the `event_rule.action` is performed (i.e. email the person who created the rule).

The application generates event objects for actions of significance at runtime and publishes them on a JMS topic. There is a process that listens on the topic for these events and when an event is received, it:

1. Persists the event object to `event_data`
2. Retrieves all `event_rule` records where `event_rule.trigger = event_data.type` and `event_rule.condition` matches against the `event_data` fields
3. For each rule that matches, perform the `event_rule.action` (the action will be interpreted and performed by application code, not in the database)

Here is a slideshow that also demonstrates what I am trying to achieve: http://www.slideshare.net/ishraqabd/publish-subscribe-model-overview-13368808 (see slides 19/20 in particular)

Essentially, I am trying to achieve this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10821/expressionconcepts.htm (see 1.3 Applying the SQL EVALUATE Operator)

My initial thought was to create a function something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION condition_matches(condition VARCHAR, data event_data)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT count(*) = 1 FROM condition_matches.data WHERE condition);
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

and used like so:

```
select rule.*
from event_rule rule
join event_data data on data.type = rule.trigger
where data.id = :eventId and condition_matches(rule.condition, data.*);
```

but i am new to postgres and unsure how to proceed. I would appreciate any other approaches that I may have overlooked as well!

Answer (score 0):

the [TRIGGER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html) functionality in PostgreSQL might help here, with creating a new row of data to flag sending an e-mail or performing the "action" in the action field, but potentially what you want to do is create a function very similar to what you described.  When passing variables to SQL in PLPGSQL, you'll often need to use the command [EXECUTE (40.5.4)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html) and then concatenate together your query in a string.  You may also want to read the section on [row types (40.3.4)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) since it looks like that's what you're trying to pass to the function with the "data" variable.

Hope this helps :)